# Check if login is correct before sending mail - Yahoo & Powershell

Tags: powershell, email, email-validation

Currently, I am trying to send email through my Yahoo account with Powershell.

I would like to know if it is possible to check if the login is valid through the given credentials.

I have looked for information through various pages and forums but I have not found anything.

Currently, I have the following code:

```
#SMTP server name
$smtpServer = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com"

#Creating a Mail object
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage

#Email structure
$msg.From = "email@domain.com"
$msg.To.Add("email@domain.com")
$msg.subject = "Subject"
$msg.body = "The Body of the email."

#Creating SMTP server object
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtp.EnableSsl = 1
$smtp.Port = 587
$cred = New-Object Net.NetworkCredential("email@domain.com","password")
$smtp.Credentials = $cred

#Sending email
$smtp.Send($msg)
```

Thank you all in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Note: Any improvements to the code for better performance/security are welcome!

Comment: Q&D (quick and dirty - send yourself a test msg using the valid creds, wait for the receive, and if successful, then send the real one.

Comment: The `.Send()` method already returns an error from the server if the credentials are incorrect: `Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated"`. The `Net.Mail.SmtpClient` class only has send methods, so there's not a way to test credentials other than by attempting to send.